# Get the last record in the database in the table 'Facture'

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the last 'Facture', but `Max` doesn't work for me:

```
Facture fac = (from c in model.Facture where c.ID = Max(ID) select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please be more clear next time, "doesn't work" is never a good description: Doesn't it compile? Compiles, but gives a runtime error? Compiles and no runtime error, but undesired or unexpected result? If so then what is your expectation vs what did you get?

Answer (score 4):

Just `OrderByDescending` by the ID and take the `Facture` with the highest

```
Facture fac = model.Facture.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you fubo it works for me

Comment: @fubo Better use SingleOrDefault if expecting only 1 record

Comment: @KingoftheNorth no; to do that you'd need to add `OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()` - but the code shown should *usually* be optimized to do that automatically (typically via `select top 1 * from Facture order by ID desc` or similar)

Comment: @MarcGravell why the Take(1)? OrderByDescending(x=>x.ID).SingleOrDefault(); works as expected

Comment: @KingoftheNorth `SingleOrDefault` only "works as expected" if you have 0 or 1 rows. The moment you get a second row, it will throw an exception. `SingleOrDefault` is *designed* to throw if more than one row comes back

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `orderby` to solve your problem.

```
Facture fac = (from c in model.Facture orderby c.ID descending select c).FirstOrDefault();
```